# How to display images from list in flutter

Tags: list, image, flutter

I created a list and add image path, and now i want to use this list and display the image in gridview, here what i'm doing

```
List imageList=["assets/img/pepsi2.jpg","assets/img/pepsi2.jpg"];



imageList.length!=0? GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap:true,
                itemCount: imageList.length,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount:2, ),
                 itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
                   return Padding(
                     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                     child: Stack(
                       children:[
                         ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                              child: Image.asset(imageList[index],
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35,
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.17,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            ),
                         Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                          child: buildCancelIcon(
                            color,
                            () {
                              setState(() {
                               _imageFileList!.removeAt(index);
                              });
                            },
                            Icons.cancel

                          ))] 
                     ),
                   );
                 }):Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 70),
          child:
              Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, children: [])),
```

but it gives me this error

`type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

please let me know how to do this

Comment: On what line does the error occure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing your image widget like this

```
Image(image: AssetImage(imageList[index]));
```